# FormGroup.controls is undefined in the custom validator

Tags: angular, formbuilder, customvalidator

I have an Ionic Project with a html page. That page has this form :

```
<form [formGroup]="configureLeagueForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label  position="floating">TEXT</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" formControlName="roundsQuantity" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="!configureLeagueForm.controls.roundsQuantity.valid  && (configureLeagueForm.controls.roundsQuantity.dirty || submitAttempt)">
      <p [class.invalid]="!configureLeagueForm.controls.roundsQuantity.valid  && (configureLeagueForm.controls.roundsQuantity.dirty || submitAttempt)" >TEXT IF ERROR .</p>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

And the .ts File

```
this.configureLeagueForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  roundsQuantity: [1, Validators.compose([Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100), ConfigureChampionshipFormValidator.roundsQuantity])],
});
```

Now, my Validator

```
export class ConfigureChampionshipFormValidator {

static roundsQuantity(group: FormGroup) : any{

var roundsQuantity = group.controls['roundsQuantity'].value;

if(String(roundsQuantity).trim() == ""){ // Just an example of validation

  group.controls['roundsQuantity'].setErrors({"mandatory_error": true});
  return { "mandatory_error": true };      
} else{
  return { "mandatory_error": false }; 
}
}

}
```

but at this step of the code :

```
group.controls['roundsQuantity'].value
```

I have group.controls as undefined.

That happens at the time I open the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your validator is set on a `FormControl` (`roundsQuantity`). So, what it will receive as argument is that form control. Not its parent form group.

Answer (score -1):

You have some issues, like mentioned in other answer, your custom validator is receiving the formcontrol, not the whole group.

Secondary, your custom validator should return `null` if the value passes the validation. `null` is considered valid in validators. So change your custom validator to:

```ts
export class ConfigureChampionshipFormValidator {
  static roundsQuantity(roundsQuantity: AbstractControl): any {
    if (!roundsQuantity.value) {
      return { "mandatory_error": true };
    } 
    return null;
  }
}
```

**[Pure Angular DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxj96s?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**